# How to filter items in the correct orderhow

Tags: javascript

Consider this array of objects and array of items i want to filter the first array to include only the objects related to the names in Array but follows the order of Array and not the order of object

```
object= [{name:'ali', age:10},{name:'max', age:5},{name:'john', age:6},{name:'well',age:12}]
Array= ['max','well','john']

const filterit= object.filter(item=>{
      if(Array.includes(item.name)
      return item.name
})
console.log(filterit)
the output result is
[{name:'max', age:5},
{name:'john', age:6},
{name:'well',age:12}]
```

the filter works perfect and only the objects related to names in Array gets filtered the only problem is that it gets filtered according to their order in the 'object' array and not according to the names order in 'Array' so how to fix this in order to get a filtered array in the same order as in Array cause order is very crucial to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this filter will not work as expected, as you `return` the item `name`, it will filter the items that have falsy value for `name`.

```
const filterit= object.filter(item=>{
  if(Array.includes(item.name))
  return item.name
})
```

You shouldn't return `item.name`, but it should return `Array.includes(item.name)`

```
 const filterit= object.filter(item => Array.includes(item.name))
```

And to make the array with the same sorting.

```js
let array = [{name:'ali', age:10},{name:'max', age:5},{name:'john', age:6},{name:'well',age:12}]

    
    let sortedArray =  []

    let namesArray = ['max','well','john']
    
    
    namesArray.forEach(name => { 
        let item = array.find(i => i.name === name)
        if (item) sortedArray.push(item)
    })
    
    
    console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate over the Array itself and filter that obj's array on match

```
consdt objArr = object= [{name:'ali', age:10},{name:'max', age:5},{name:'john', age:6},{name:'well',age:12}]
const myArr = ['max','well','john']    
const result = myArr.filter(elem => {
return objArr.find(item => item.name == elem)
})
```

Comment: `filter` expects a boolean to be returned from the callback. `find` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: but this returns just the names property  and not the object itself after i return the object in the correct order i am going to work on the age value and do calculation find didn't return the age property as well